# onSet function does not get fired on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-stickit

I am stacking at how to fire stickit onSet event by custom event.

In the code below,`colorChange` event is properly occurring and all bindings(stickit) events work properly as well but `onSet` event.

Could someone point out where the wrong point is?

```
bindings: {
  '#color1': {
    observe: 'color1',
    update : function($el,val){
      $el.css("background-color",val);
    },
    onSet : function(){
    //never get fired
    },
    events : ["colorChange"]
  }
}

events : {
  "colorChange" : function(){
    //the event is occurring
  }
}

//somewhere

$("#color1").trigger("colorChange");

<!-- in the html -->
<div id="color1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is bit hacky though I've found a way to make it.

stickit 2way binding works only on form element and element which has `contenteditable="true"` like @mavarazy mentioned.

before calling `stickit()` set the div into `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` and

```
bindings: {
  '#color1': {
    observe: 'color1',
    initialize : function($el){
      $el.removeAttr("contenteditable")
    },
    update : function($el,val){
      $el.css("background-color",val);
    },
    onSet : function(){
    //gets the event
    },
    events : ["colorChange"]
  }
}
```

delete the attribute not to let it real editable element after initializing
and it works as 2way binding now.

Answer (score 1):

Stickit uses 2 way binding on form elements, which are *input, textarea, input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio], select*; for everything else StickIt goes with 1 way binding.

You should specify *color1* id on your form element.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but it can help others. The easier way is just add  `updateModel: true`

```
bindings: {
  '#color1': {
    observe: 'color1',
    update : function($el,val){
      $el.css("background-color",val);
    },
    onSet : function(){
    //gets the event
    },
    updateModel: true,
    events : ["colorChange"]
  }
}
```